# Get all data from mysql row in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm stuck on something small, hope you can help me..

I need all phone numbers (thats a column in table 'leerlingen') in one here, with comma's separated, so I can insert that here in another script and it shows all phone numbers, like this:

```
0612345637,061231823,061231723
```

**Code:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leerlingen
WHERE klas_id='$aan_klas'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $variabele = $row['leerling_nummer'] . ",";

  echo "$variabele";
  }
```

But, when I `echo $variabele` *OUTSIDE* the while loop, it only gives me ONE phone number.
When I `echo $variabele` *INSIDE* the while loop, it shows me all the phone numbers, on the right way.. Any ideas?

**Edit**

my code isn't working at all I see, so here's what I want: It should get all phone numbers seperated with a comma, put in a variabele or array.

**Edit**

Thanks guys, it's workign! But... only when al mysql_ things ARE mysql_. When I change them to mysqli_, nothing happens...

Comment: Don't use mysql_* statement, they're obsolete. Prefer using mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: mysql_* is been deprecate din further versions of php need to use pdo objects or mysqli_* for that

Comment: Everytime, $variabele will have the latest phone number only. Because, it gets overwritten. Simple take an array and then implode with comma.

Comment: You should check out GROUP_CONCAT in mySQL which might be very useful to solve your problem. Check out this demo how to do this: http://www.giombetti.com/2013/06/06/mysql-group_concat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing **all** phone numbers when you `echo "$variabele";` **inside** the while loop, is because on each iteration (every time the while loop is re-entered, so to speak) you are echoing the last value of `$variabele`. And so, it **looks** as though everything was `echo`'d all at once, when in fact it is `echo`'d one at a time.

You can easily demonstrate this by altering the code to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $variabele = $row['leerling_nummer'] . ",";
    echo "$variabele" . " | ";
}
```

Now, you will see the result is not (as I think you expected):

`0612345637,061231823,061231723, |`

... but:

`0612345637, | 061231823, | 061231723, |`

If what you believed was happening, was **really** happening, then the result would actually be this:

`0612345637, | 0612345637, 061231823, | 0612345637, 061231823, 061231723, |`

If you want to collect all phone numbers in one variable, you'd indeed be best off by using an array, as [Mark Baker already proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020132/get-all-data-from-mysql-row-in-a-variabele#14020154), **or** you would have to append each new phone number to the `$variabele` string, like so:

```
// initiate $variabele as an empty string
$variabele = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // append the new phone number to $variabele (note .= in stead of =)
    $variabele .= $row['leerling_nummer'] . ",";
}
echo $variabele;
```

The only problem with this, is that you'd have to remove the last comma then. There are a variety of ways to do this, or circumvent this, but Mark Baker's solution is much simpler actually.

Lastly, I want to make you aware of a nifty MySQL function that allows you to easily concatenate values of a column; this is the function `GROUP_CONCAT()`. This, however, is probably not useful in your current case, since you are fetching other columns as well. But for future reference, if you only need one column want to concatenate them with a comma, you could do:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( leerling_nummer ) AS leerling_nummers
FROM leerlingen
WHERE klas_id='$aan_klas'
GROUP BY klas_id
```

After querying the database and then doing `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` all numbers would then be in `$row['leerling_nummers']`, seperated by a comma, because `GROUP_CONCAT()` uses a comma as a default separator. In other words: you wouldn't need to loop over rows with PHP anymore; MySQL has already collected everything in one row for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is what arrays are designed for

```
$variabele = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if($row['leerling_nummer'] != '')
        $variabele[] = $row['leerling_nummer'];
  }
  echo implode(', ', $variabele);
```

Comment: When you echo __what__ it says array? are you simply echoing $variabele without the implode?

Comment: @Jellevdschoot implode will return a string. Store that string in some variable and then echo it. Something like $str = implode(',', $variabele); and then echo $str

Comment: No, I'm echo'ing     echo implode(', ', $variabele);

Comment: @BhavikShah thanks for your reply, but when I echo $str it isn't showing anything..

Comment: It's working now, thanks Mark & Bhavik! But.. It's only working with mysql_, when I change that to mysqli_ it's not working..

Comment: @Jellevdschoot try var_dump($str) and also check that $variabele is not an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenation:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leerlingen WHERE klas_id='$aan_klas'");

$variabele="";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $variabele .= $row['leerling_nummer'] . ",";
  }
echo "VAR: $variabele";
```

Aside from that, please consider using msqli_ or PDO since mysql_ functions are deprecated!

Comment: You don't need double quotes in the last line.

Comment: yup it's true, normally you'll want to add something beside the variable and I forgot to remove them!

Comment: Be aware that this solution will have a trailing comma. Also, mysql_ functions are not yet deprecated, but will be as of PHP version `5.5.0` (which is still in alpha stage). It's still very wise to use either PDO or MySQLi indeed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, it seems not working with `mysqli`.
Here is a `mysqli` solution:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM leerlingen WHERE klas_id='$aan_klas'");    
$variabele = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['leerling_nummer']){
        $variabele .= $row['leerling_nummer'] . ",";
    }
}
echo rtrim($variabele, ',');
?>
```

The `mysqli_query()` expects the first parameter to be a link resource which returns from `mysqli_connect()`.

```
<?php
    $mysqlserver   = "localhost";
    $mysqlusername = "root";
    $mysqlpassword = "";
    $link = mysqli_connect(localhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysqli_error());
?>
```