# Get all rows into a variable then mailto for each PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

So, I found this thread ([Get all data from mysql row in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020132/get-all-data-from-mysql-row-in-a-variable)) but I am too much of a beginner to make it apply easily to my situation. Thank you for helping me out... sorry for the total newb questions.

I have a PHP form that lets the user select one of my tables in a database where email addresses are stored to send an email to each of them. Right now, I have this code:

```
    $recipientid = $_POST['recipientid'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: SENDER NAME <senderemail@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $time = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    $sendbody = $body . "<br><br>This is a bulk email announcement sent by 
the institution.<br><br>It was sent at " . $time . ". If you have any 
questions about this message or wish to unsubscribe, please contact 
the institution.";
    if($recipientid == 'allstudents'){ 
        // SEE NOTE #2//
        $recipientlist = //email addresses
    }

    $process=explode(",",$recipientlist);
    reset($process);
    foreach ($process as $to) {
    $sent=mail($to,$subject,$sendbody,$headers);
    }
    if ($sent) { //(success echo goes here... it is quite long so i removed it.)
    } else {
    echo "Email could not be sent, PLEASE CONTACT US.";
    }
```

What is the easiest way to capture all of the email addresses in the column of the specified table and then loop a mailto for each? **I was originally trying to get them all into one string and then explode them as you can see, but that might not be the best solution.** Am I on the right track here?

(NOTE #2 FROM IF)
HERE IS WHERE I NEED SOMETHING... I was sort of thinking about trying to use the following. I need it to grab all the emails from the column emailaddresses in the table students. I am using an if statement because there are four other things that $recipientid could equal, and each different one grabs email addresses from a different table. 
`array pg_fetch_all_columns ( resource $result [, int $column = 3 ] )` But then, I don't know how to get this array to work with my mail. I originally tried to use just a SELECT * from emailaddresses and then use each row somehow but I don't know how to implement that.

YES, I know I am using mysql not mysqli and I know that mailto is probably not the best solution, but it is what I have to work with right now (unless you can suggest an alternative route for the mail loop).

Thank you again! I really want to learn what I am doing, so an explanation would be appreciated:)

(and ps I am using the mail function with the explode because of this article http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/php-script/how-to-send-out-mass-emails-php-script/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a little confused about the question. It sounds like you have a database with email address and you want to send an email for each email address. I think you can just do the query SELECT emailaddress from table and cycle through the results and use your mail function each time.

```
$query = *your select query*

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $sent=mail($row['emailadress'],$subject,$sendbody,$headers);

  if ($sent) { //(success echo goes here... it is quite long so i removed it.)
  } else {
  echo "Email could not be sent, PLEASE CONTACT US.";
  }
```

If you want your user to select the table the email addresses are coming from you can use a form and a variable in the query.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, but I need each of the emails to be sent individually because i do not want recipients to see the other recipients. How can I make this a loop to do one at a time?

Comment: It should be doing it one at a time already. the while loop goes row by row and puts the current row into $row[]. It gets overwritten when the loops goes to the next row.

Comment: Oh oh oh. Thank you I didn't understand how while worked... Hahaha. You've been a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below piece of code to send the mail.
Consider you have an email field in your table 'students'
then

```
$sel = mysql_query("select email from students");
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel))
{
  $to = $info['email'];
  $sent=mail($to,$subject,$sendbody,$headers);
  //---Remaining code goes on
}
```

try it.